# Round function off by 1 - C

Tags: c, cs50

```
char note_array[] = "G#5";

int approx_freq = 880;

int result = 0;
if(note_array[1] == '#')
    approx_freq = round(approx_freq * pow(2, 1.0/12));
switch(note_array[0])
{
case 'A': result =  approx_freq;
    break;
case 'B': result = round(approx_freq * pow(2, 2.0/12));
    break;
case 'C': result = round(approx_freq / pow(2, 9.0/12));
    break;
case 'D': result = round(approx_freq / pow(2, 7.0/12));
    break;
case 'E': result = round(approx_freq / pow(2, 5.0/12));
    break;
case 'F': result = round(approx_freq / pow(2, 4.0/12));
    break;
case 'G': result = round(approx_freq / pow(2.0, 2.0/12));
    break;
default: return 1;
    break;
}
return result;
```

Output Coming - 830

Output Needed - 831

I know there is something wrong with my usage of the round function, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. 
Can anybody please help me out?

Comment: If you want to round you up need `ceil` instead of `round`

Comment: If the computer say it's 830, it's indeed 830. Does your manual computation says otherwise?

Comment: But I need 12 if the o/p is 12.4 and 13 if the o/p is 12.6.

Comment: So ceil won't let me do that.

Comment: I'm doing a course CS50, and it's checking alg shows it must be 831

Comment: Your computer does what you **tell** it does, not what you **think** it does.

Comment: Again, calculate it manually, or use a debugger to see that each step it performs is completely correct as how you **tell** it does.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: And I know i'm telling it something wrong, that's why I came here.

Comment: Try to debug your program before asking on Stack Overflow. [How much effort is expected of StackOverflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) / ["If you went from "something's not working" to "asking a question" in less than 10 minutes, you probably haven't done enough research."](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: But why didn't this question appear in my new list of questions? Now when I hard refreshed it appeared with 2 good answers.

Comment: Don't edit the question to say it's solved. Accepting an answer is the way to show that.

Comment: `pow(2.0, x/12)` are constants so it's better to store them in constants instead of calculating them again and again everytime you entered the switch block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're rounding down when you do this step:

```
approx_freq = round(approx_freq * pow(2, 1.0/12));
```

The exact value is `932.3275230361799`. This sets `approx_freq` to `932`. Then when you do:

```
case 'G': result = round(approx_freq / pow(2.0, 2.0/12));
    break;
```

`approx_freq / pow(2.0, 2.0/12))` is `830.3176053067962`, which rounds to `830`.

You shouldn't do rounding in your intermediate steps. Declare `approx_freq` to be `float` or `double`, and only round the final result. Then the last calculation will result in `830.609`, which rounds up to `831`.

Comment: Not sure why anyone considers this question off-topic, and there are no close votes. He posted code, he posted what he expected and what he got instead.

Answer (score 2):

Introduce an offset for selecting the border at which rounding down turns into rounding up. Do so in all calls to `round()`, e.g.

```
approx_freq = round(offset + approx_freq * pow(2, 1.0/12));
```

I am not sure, but I guess that the value of `offset` should be -0.5 for what you want.
Try and fine-tune yourself.

(Note, as other comments/answers have noted, that when to round is a tricky question. I recommend using the offset after double checking that rounding is needed in each case.)